# SSO using OIDC not working for electron apps for Azure AD joined devices

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, electron, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

I am trying to achieve SSO for my electron based app with pure Azure AD cloud only user. The device is joined to Azure AD and logged in user is an AAD user. SSO is working seamlessly with Edge and IE and also with Google chrome(with Windows 10 Accounts extension added). But, whenever I try to launch the URL with Electron it always takes me to the auth page rather than retrieving the auth code.

PS: I have already tried the below

1. Adding "https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com" and AAD server to auth-server-whitelist and auth-negotiate-delegatewhitelist.
2. Add the urls to session.defaultSession.allowNTLMCredentialsForDomains('*')
3. Changing the UsrAgentFallback to Edg/version from Electron/version

Same setup works if the user is federated via Azure AD connect with both on prem and AAD server but is not working in pure Azure AD environment. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hi, @Ankit. Have you solved your problem? I'm having a very similar case.